# Obtaining only first result from a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, left-join

I'm trying to get the first result of a `LEFT JOIN` for each row of a `SELECT` statement.

Because now right now, if I have 100 rows in the joined table, I'll get 100 times the same row from the `SELECT`. I'd just need the first joined row so that way I wouldn't get any duplicates.

I can't use `GROUP BY` because I have to get more than only one row from the table.

Here's a basic version of my query:

```
SELECT bg.PatientID, DATEDIFF(hour, bg.CreateDate, GETDATE()) TimeToTarget 
FROM BloodGlucose bg
    LEFT JOIN IVProtocol i ON i.PatientID = bg.PatientID
WHERE bg.BGValue >= i.TargetLow AND bg.BGValue <= i.TargetHigh
ORDER BY bg.PatientID ASC
```

I tried using `DISTINCT` but since the data from `bg.CreateDate` isn't always the same it returns duplicates.

I just need the FIRST row of that left joined table.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you define "`FIRST`"?

Comment: I'd need the first result fetched from the `LEFT JOIN`. But telling you so, I guess I'll need a subquery since there's no order on joins...

Comment: Yes, I still don't know what you mean by "first result"

Comment: That join returns about hundreds of result, I just need the first result of the join. So by this I actually mean the last inserted row of that joined table.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't track "last inserted" so you still need to help define what that means. Does `CreatedDate` indicate that? If so, that was the assumption I had already made in my query. Did you try either of the posted solutions?

Comment: Joined table's ID defines that, also CreateDate defines this. So bg.BGID or bg.CreateDate should help to define what's the last inserted row. Thanks for the help by the way! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT bg.PatientID, DATEDIFF(hour, bg.CreateDate, GETDATE()) TimeToTarget 
FROM BloodGlucose bg
cross apply (
 select top 1 *
 from IVProtocol i
 where i.PatientID = bg.PatientID
 order by SOME_CRITERA
) i
WHERE bg.BGValue >= i.TargetLow AND bg.BGValue <= i.TargetHigh
ORDER BY bg.PatientID ASC
```

Cross apply is a handy tool for such situations. It works like a join but you can use variables inside the subquery.

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    bg.PatientID, 
    TimeToTarget = DATEDIFF(hour, bg.CreateDate, GETDATE()),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bg.PatientID ORDER BY bg.CreatedDate DESC) 
  FROM dbo.BloodGlucose AS bg
  LEFT JOIN dbo.IVProtocol AS i 
  ON i.PatientID = bg.PatientID
  WHERE bg.BGValue >= i.TargetLow 
  AND bg.BGValue <= i.TargetHigh
)
SELECT PatientID, TimeToTarget
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY PatientID;
```

To join to other results:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  ... same as above ...
)
SELECT x.PatientID, x.TimeToTarget, y.Something
 FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.SomethingElse AS y
 ON x.PatientID = y.PatientID
 WHERE x.rn = 1
 ORDER BY x.PatientID;
```

Comment: That works awesomely. The only problem I'm having is that I have to put that query in another query's JOIN statement and right now it seems to have trouble doing so with the WITH. But still this works, I'll try to fit it in. Thanks!

Comment: You can join to `x` after the CTE.